# OCSINVENTORY ISSUES agent dosent communicate with the server

Tags: ocs-inventory-ng

I installed OCSINVENTORY successfully. The problem is that I can't get any information from OCS agent installed in others machines.

Any help please, or an idea where the problem is?

Comment: My best gues at this point is that you are looking for [this information](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php?title=Documentation:Main#Network_Discovery_with_OCS_Inventory_NG) but I can't be certain due to that lack of detail in your question. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] any pertinent details into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: finally it works , the problem was in the agent version , it was incompatible , now i m using ocs agent version 2.0.5

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted! Your experience might be useful to other members if you would flesh out your question a bit with the versions of OCSINVENTORY and the agent version you were using and write up your solution as an answer. Best regards!

Comment: i think the ocs server version is 2.2.1 , and 2  of theagent version works well . agent version 2.0.5 and 2.1.1.1

Comment: This could be useful information to share, however answers belong in the answer box. Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/993647/ocsinventory-issues-agent-dosent-communicate-with-the-server?noredirect=1#comment1603637_993647  and then https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer